Two or more files get the same variable
As title.
I have variable file A,
global var = 0

program file B,
import A

for i in range(1000):
    A.var += 1
    time.sleep(1)

and program file C:
print(A.var)

Then,what can I do to let B or C get the same variable A?
For example, result C is 60 when B has been running for 60s.

Like you can get it in file B, by importing A?

Are you saying you want to run python B.py, and then 60 seconds later, run python C.py and have it get information about the state of A.var from the process you started 60 seconds ago?

Is your issue about the "get the variable (A.var of B) by C" part, or about the "by C when B is running" part? These are very distinct.

global is used inside of a function to tell python that a variable is not local. Otherwise, if a variable is assigned in a function, it is assumed to be local to the function. In your case, there was no need for global since you are not in a function.

@tdelaney The global isn't just unnecessary, it' nonsense. global var = 0 is a Syntax Error.

You already managed to get and modify A.var in B. What is stopping you from getting it in C the same way? Please [edit] your question clarify what exactly you are asking.

From reading this I get the impression the OP needs to be taught about the relation of files and processes. Not sure what reading/watching to advice for that.

I am sorry to have confused. Infact, I want to make a monitoring system. Let B complete and let C to check it. However,the variable A is too big to fast transfer. Therefore, I want to ask the question: Can I base the variable A and let both of B and C get at the same time? (Like pointer to address)

Variables in Python are literally pointers in the CPython implementation. No single variable can be "too big to fast transfer" in a setup similar to what you show here. Again, what trouble do you have accessing A inside C the same way you already access A inside B?

Accroding to the question. I can't let Process B and Process C to get the same variable. Following both B and C import A, or C import B. Now,I let B to write to disk, and C get it. initiative. May I change the way about wirte to disk?

@LittleSun Why can’t you let them get the same variable? At the running in different threads, different processes, or on different machines, for example?

Ya. It's my original question. What can I do to let them get the same variable?

@LittleSun What is your original question? The question hasn’t had any content like this added or removed. Please [edit] the question to include relevant details.

@MisterMiyagi Sorry. I'm edit it. Is it ok?

Variables exist in a namespace. When you
import A

you are assigning A.py's namespace to the variable A in your module's namespace. Any other module that does the same import gets a reference to A's namespace in their module's namespace.
An operation like
A.var += 1

looks up "var" in A's namespace, performs the operation and assigns back to that same namespace. That's why all modules that import the same way see the same value.
As long as B and C are importing in the same program, they will see the same A namespace and thus the same variables in A.

I am sorry to have confused. I want to ask the question about both of different programs use same variables. Accroding to the issue and following your process(Make C import A), B is running and C is always 1.
